# Using IF in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list

I am trying to reproduce an Excel formula in a SharePoint List.

Below is the Excel Formula:

```
=IF(H2="",DAYS(TODAY(),G2),DAYS(H2,G2))
```

Below is what I am having in SharePoint:

```
=IF([Aproved]="",DAYS(TODAY(),[Created]),DAYS([Created], [Approved]))
```

However it is always throwing an error message.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you trying to find the number of days between Today and Created date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of days between two days then you have to use `DATEDIF` function in SharePoint calculated columns:

```
DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d")
```

Try using below formula:

```
=IF([Approved]="", DATEDIF(NOW(),[Created],"d"),DATEDIF([Created],[Approved],"d"))
```

To check if column is blank you can also use `ISBLANK` function(I am not sure why you are using empty string comparison).

```
ISBLANK([Approved])
```

**Reference**:

[SharePoint Calculated Column Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#date-and-time-formulas).

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Approved),DATEDIF(Created,TODAY(),"d"),DATEDIF(Created,Approved,"d"))
```

Notice that Today() in the calculated column cannot update automatically, you need to update the column manually or use tools such as workflow to update.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling of "Approved"/"Aproved"?

```
=IF([Aproved]="",DAYS(TODAY(),[Created]),DAYS([Created], [Approved]))
```

But do keep in mind Hellofiona_MSFT's point about TODAY().